# How to update admin.py in django-registration-redux?

Tags: django, python-3.x, django-forms, django-registration

`RequestSite` is no longer in django.contrib.sites.models but is in django.contrib.sites.requests. I found that when I installed django-registration-redux, those old import statements are still there. So it raises the following errors:

```
from django.contrib.sites.models import RequestSite
ImportError: cannot import name 'RequestSite'
```

So how can I fix it? How do I replace `RequestSite` in `python3.4/site-packages/registration/admin.py` file? I am using django-registration-redux 1.2, Django 1.9 and Python 3.4.

Comment: This looks related: https://github.com/macropin/django-registration/issues/132

Comment: yeah but i didn't get my answer there so i have posted this here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`RequestSite` is under `django.contrib.sites.requests`

so replace: `from django.contrib.sites.models import RequestSite`
with: `from django.contrib.sites.requests import RequestSite`

Reference: (https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/ref/contrib/sites/#requestsite-objects)

Comment: i did this but it raised further errors. Then i uninstalled version 1.2 and installed manually django-registration-redux 1.3. Thanks for you support!